# Visual explanation of $\pi$ series definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, pi, visualization

Can you visually explain why the following is true:

$$
\frac{\pi}{4} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k + 1} = \frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}\ldots\approx 78.5\%
$$

By visually I mean use a circle and square to help me understand rather than some calculus that I won't understand.

I have recently been very intrigued by $\pi /4$ as it seems to make geometry simpler. For example, the area of a circle is $\pi /4$ times the area of its circumscribed square, and the circle's perimeter is $\pi /4$ times the perimeter of its circumscribed square. See more here: [Geometry with $\pi /4$](https://stackedit.io/viewer#!provider=gist&gistId=9100392&filename=Geometry.md)

Comment: "Visually"? Like in TV or what in the world do you mean??

Comment: I don't believe there are any visual explanations. It's true because of the Taylor/MacLaurin series for $\text{arc} \tan$.

Comment: @DonAntonio I would assume he wants an intuitive, geometrical explanation, and in my opinion, so should you. Back to the problem at hand, if you're talking about visualisations about $\pi/4$, then the area of a quarter of a circle with radius $1$ might work. The square that shares two sides with the quarter circle has area $1$, so that seems a good place to start. See if you can find a way to remove a third of an area, then add back a fifth and so on to approximate the circle boundary. With some luck you can get nice calculations to go along with it. At least that's what I'd try first.

Comment: @Arthur, the issue is to connect the geometric notion of pi to the given expansion.

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Infinite_series), and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80). Those may not be geometrical explanations, but I don't know any. In analysis one needs analytical definitions. I don't remember anymore why this is the same as the geometrical $\pi$, but it is. Consider for instance that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are defined through the exponent function.

Comment: Well I don't have an answer - but this exercise visualizes the beauty of this series: take a string (lets say 1m long) and straighten it, then take a string (1/3 m long) and align it with one end, then take a string (1/5) meters long and align it with the  inward end of the 1/3 m string and so forth…. You, will approach a length of pi/4 meters with this "algorithm". Stunning!

Comment: "Should I", @Arthur ? How can you know?

Comment: @Just_a_fool I don't see what's so stunning about that, that's just a restatement of the series..

Comment: @DonAntonio This is the second time in a week I've seen you write like that on something that's not written 100% to your liking. Honestly, I think this site would be better without such comments. Telling people that they've not chosen the best words and suggesting improvements is good. Correcting people by being nasty and sarcastic is unnecessary. That's how I see it. A "visual explanation" can only really mean one thing, and from someone who's been on this site long enough to gather $86,000$ reputation it is my honest opinion that you are expected to know better than "Like in TV or what?".

Comment: That's your opinion, @Arthur. Mine, as a mathematician, is that anyone at high school level or over *must*, and it's expected to, be as clear and accurate as possible when dealing with our craft. And if you think I was being nasty and sarcastic by my first comment (I suppose) then I'm afraid it's possible you'll be deeply dissapointed in the future. Your way of seeing things, like in "visual", doesn't really matter here. The point imo is, or should be: "am I being clear?" In your case I can honestly say you weren't, at least as far as I see it:I didn't have the slightest idea what you meant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Historically, there are three main independent (re)discoveries of this series formula for $\pi/4$:

- by the German mathematican Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz (1646–1716),
- by the Scottish mathematician James Gregory (1638–1675), and
- by Indian mathematicians, attributed to Madhava of Sangamagrama (roughly 1340–1425), but available only through citations of successors like Nilakantha Somayaji (1444–1544).

All three are discussed in the article [*The Discovery of the Series Formula for π* by Ranjan Roy](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/carl-b-allendoerfer-awards/the-discovery-of-the-series-formula-for-pi), published in Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 63 (1990), pp. 291-306, which won the [Carl B. Allendoerfer award](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/carl-b-allendoerfer-awards) in 1991.

Of the three, let me take up Mādhava's, because as the earliest one, it certainly predates (what is regarded as) the development of calculus, and because I find it the simplest geometrically.

It and other early results leading up to some aspects of calculus are also discussed in K. Ramasubramanian and M. D. Srinivas (2010), [*Development of calculus in India,*](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/india_calculus.pdf) Studies in the history of Indian mathematics, 201-286.

---

Consider a unit circle, and in particular one particular quarter-circle of it, bounded by a unit square.

[image: Figure 5 from Roy's article, with diagonal added]

We want to find the length of half the arc $AC$, which we know is $\pi/4$.

We divide the side $AB$ into $n$ equal parts of length $\frac1n$ each. Consider the $r$th such part, $P_{r-1} P_r$. Drop perpendiculars $P_{r-1}D$ and $EF$ onto $OP_r$. We have from similarity of triangles,

- $\displaystyle \frac{EF}{OE} = \frac{P_{r-1}D}{OP_{r-1}}$ (sine of the small angle at $O$) and
- $\displaystyle \frac{P_{r-1}D}{P_{r-1}P_r} = \frac{OA}{OP_r}$ (sine of the angle $DP_rP_{r-1}$)

so we get

$$EF = OE\frac{P_{r-1}D}{OP_{r-1}} = OE\frac{P_{r-1}P_r\frac{OA}{OP_r}}{OP_{r-1}} = \frac{P_{r-1}P_r}{OP_r \times OP_{r-1}}$$
where I dropped $OE$ and $OA$ because they are unit lengths.

Now, for large $n$ (as $n \to \infty$), the arc segment $EG \approx EF$, and the total arc length (of half the quarter-cicle) is the sum of these corresponding arc lengths $EG$, so they argued that (in modern notation)

$$\frac{\pi}{4} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{P_{r-1}P_r}{OP_r \times OP_{r-1}}.$$

Further, the numerator $P_{r-1}P_r = 1/n$ by definition, and for large $n$, the denominator $OP_r OP_{r-1}$ can be approximated by $OP_r^2 = 1 + AP_r^2 = 1 + (r/n)^2$ (actually they were more sophisticated and used the fact that it is bounded by $OP_{r-1}^2$ and $OP_r^2$, etc.), so we have

$$\frac{\pi}{4} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1/n}{1 + (r/n)^2}$$

The rest is easy: use the fact that
$$\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \dots$$
with $x = (r/n)^2$ so that our sum is 
$$\frac1n \sum_{r=1}^n (1 - (r/n)^2 + (r/n)^4 - (r/n)^6 + \dots)$$

Also, they had proved that in general 
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^k \approx \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1},$$
so
$$\frac1n \sum_{r=1}^n (r/n)^k \approx \frac1{k+1}$$
(being equal in the limit), so that in the limit our sum becomes
$$\frac{\pi}{4} = 1 - \frac13 + \frac15 - \frac17 + \dots.$$

I have been a bit even more informal in the above argument (with interchanging sums, taking limits, etc.) than they were, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for the links! By combining your explanation with the article's I was able to get a pretty good grasp on the process.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Note that the same argument also gives, in general, that $$\tan^{-1} a = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{an} \frac{1/n}{1 + (r/n)^2} = \int_0^a \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx$$

Comment: To be precise, this series is attributed to Mādhava because later authors have quoted him, but the first available *proof*, following the above, comes from the text Yuktibhāṣā c. 1530. I wrote more about it, following the translation of the text closely, [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12976/yuktibh%c4%81%e1%b9%a3%c4%81-16th-century-first-modern-proof-of-frac-pi4-int-01-fracdt/14454#14454).

Answer (score 1):

You should know that:
$$\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\tan^{-1}(1)$$
This means that:
$$\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{1+x^2} \ dx$$
We will use the rule that $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8\dots \ (-1\le x \le 1)$.
$$\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\int_0^1 1 -x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8\dots \ dx$$
We will solve the indefinite integral $\int 1 -x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8\dots \ dx$ first. This is basically power rule repeated an infinite number of times.
$$\int 1 -x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8\dots \ dx$$
$$= x - \dfrac{x^3}{3} + \dfrac{x^5}{5} - \dfrac{x^7}{7} + \dfrac{x^9}{9} \dots + C$$
Now we will evaluate the definite integral. We just need to use the **Fundamental Theorem of Calculus** to do this. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is this:
*Suppose $G$ is an antiderivative of $f$. Then:*
$$\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = G(b) - G(a)$$
To find the definite integral, we just have to plug in the value of $b$ (which is $1$) into the antiderivative (which is basically the answer to the integral) and evaluate it. Then we plug in $a$ to the antideravitave and evaluate it. Finally, we subtract the second value ($G(a)$) from the first value ($G(b)$).
$$\dfrac{\pi}{4}= \left(1 - \dfrac{1^3}{3}+\dfrac{1^5}{5}-\dfrac{1^7}{7}+\dfrac{1^9}{9}\dots + C \right) - \left(0 - \dfrac{0^3}{3}+\dfrac{0^5}{5}-\dfrac{0^7}{7}+\dfrac{0^9}{9}\dots + C \right)$$
$$\dfrac{\pi}{4}= 1 - \dfrac{1^3}{3}+\dfrac{1^5}{5}-\dfrac{1^7}{7}+\dfrac{1^9}{9}\dots + C - C$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\dfrac{\pi}{4}= 1 - \dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}\dots}$$

Comment: I understand your first equation, though I'm not familiar with integrals, so i'm not sure how you got your second equation. Your third equation is [true when $|x| > 1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29+%3D+sum+%28-1%29%5Ek*x%5E%282k%29%2C+k%3D0+to+infinity), but I've no clue how you got your 5th equation from your 3rd. Not super visual, but thanks!

Comment: @Web_Designer I explained it a little better now

Comment: This doesn't appear to engage with the question. OP was asking for a geometric/visual explanation "rather than some calculus [he] won't understand"

Comment: Maybe if we can geometrically interpret the equations $\tan^{-1}y=\int_0^y\frac1{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ and $\frac1{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots$ we will arrive at the desired visual explanation.

Comment: @rahul This may be feasible as an 'area under curve' style argument based on the usual arc from $0$ to $y$ radians?

Answer (score 0):

Its the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$.

Comment: Do you have a clean and geometric way of showing that this integral is connected to the series? Because that's twhat the OP wants.

Comment: The series converges absolutely for $|x| < 1$ so you can just integrate term by term. Set $y = - x^2$, $$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{1-y} = 1 + y + y^2 + ... = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - ...$$ Integrating and taking $x = 1$ gets the series, no?