# Are there any formulas or identities that involves $\pi$ but have no obvious trigonometric interpretation?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, geometric-interpretation

Every formula that involves $\pi$ has an underlying trigonometric interpretation but it is not usually obvious.

I wonder if there are any formula like the Gaussian integral $f_{n}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi n^2}} \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2n^2}\right)$ which contains $\pi$ but does not have any obvious trigonometric interpretation.

Comment: This question has thousands of possible answers; a better question would be which identities DO have a natural geometric interpretation.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689315) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of squarefree numbers (numbers not divisible by any square number other than 1) less than $n$ is asymptotically equal to $6n/\pi^2$.

The number of pairs $a,b$ with $0\le a\le n$, $0\le b\le n$, $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is asymptotically $6n^2/\pi^2$.

I wrote an expository paper on the number of three-term geometric progressions with all terms less than $n$, and the answer came out to involve $\pi$. I'll come back with more details.

EDIT: [Here's](http://www.austms.org.au/Gazette/2008/Jul08/TechPaperMyerson.pdf) the paper. The number of three-term geometric progressions $a,b,c$ with $1\le a\le b\le c\le n$ is asymptotically $(3/\pi^2)n\log n$.

Answer (score 5):

The [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) was one of the earlier examples of this.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Comment: Not quite obvious, but many of the solutions of the Basel problem do involve trigonometric functions, e.g. Euler's original solution using an infinite product representation of $\sin(x)/x$.  Does that count as "trigonometric interpretation"?

Comment: Also $\sum n^{-4}=\pi^4/90$, $\sum n^{-6}=\pi^6/945$, ....