# How is it that $\pi$ appears in so many formulas that seem to be in no way geometric.

Tags: geometry, summation, pi

When I first saw:

$$\frac{\pi}{4}=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}\mp\cdots.$$

I was puzzled that such an expression could have anything to do with circles. There are tons more and it seems like a very large amount of summations will end up having to do with $\pi$. My question is how come $\pi$ finds its way into so many formulas, and could the above equation be thought of geometrically.

Comment: It appears in that formula because it has to do with a trig function which is geometric. How often "should" you see something somewhere you don't expect it?

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689315) question.