# What are some interesting un-intuitive problems in probability aside from Monty Hall?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, soft-question, intuition, independence

Does anyone know of some interesting and almost strange problems in probability?

I know that probability is sometimes notorious for being mind-bending and un-intuitive! (Monty Hall is already an obvious one)

Comment: The birthday problem is not intuitive, or it is not common to be intuitive.

Comment: @Brofessor: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1646548) answer shows an unintuitive answer to a probability question, in my opinion.

Comment: sleeping beauty paradox and envelope swap game paradox - see them at Wikipedia

Answer (score 4):

Shuffle a deck of cards (standard $52$-card bridge deck) and deal one card. What's the probability that it's an ace? The answer is $\frac1{13},$ nothing unintuitive about that.

Shuffle a deck of cards and deal one card after another until an ace is dealt, then deal one more card. What 's the probability that the last card is an ace? Intuitiveness is a matter of opinion; personally, I find it kind of unintuitive that the probability is still $\frac1{13}.$

(More generally, for $n\ge k\ge2,$ if balls are drawn one by one without replacement from an urn containing $n$ balls of which $k$ are black, then the probability that the first black ball is immediately followed by another black ball is equal to $k/n.$)

Comment: My first thought on this answer was: "Is this really true?" That distrust confirms that I share your opinion.

Comment: On average we expect the first ace to be the thirteenth card. Then the calculation for the second ace is $3/39=1/13$. Of course, "then" has no meaning here (we're talking about an average, not a single experiment), but I think this is a fairly intuitive (if naïve) reason to believe the answer.

Comment: Page 11 of this pdf for answer to a related problem! http://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_1.pdf

Comment: @WillR Actually the expected number of cards dealt, up to and including the first ace, is $\frac{52+1}{4+1}=10.6,$ not $13.$

Comment: @WillR The reasoning that led you to believe that "on average we expect the first ace to be the 13th card" would probably also lead you to believe that "on average we expect the first red ace to be the 26th card" and "on average we expect the ace of hearts to be the 52nd card." That least one is clearly off, isn't it?

Comment: @bof: Yes, I was clearly mistaken. At least it might sound convincing to the uninitiated! Dealing cards from a deck of 52 is not the same as dealing cards from an infinite deck, where each next card has a (constant) 1/13 chance of being an ace. Am I right in thinking the expected time until an ace would then be 13? My instinct is to model it as a geometric distribution, which is probably what I was subconsciously doing (incorrectly) with the deck of cards earlier.

Comment: @WillR In other words, if you're sampling **with replacement** from a standard deck, the expected waiting time for the first ace is $13.$ Of course, putting those non-aces back in the deck and reshuffling will **increase** the waiting time! So without replacement the expected wait is $\lt13$ and if I figured it right it's $\frac{53}5.$

Answer (score 2):

[Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) : mixing does not preserve correlation sign (the mixing of two distributions having positive correlation on a pair of components can produce a distribution with negative correlation). Perhaps you need to be familiar with contingency tables to better grasp why this is surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the oldest, that still gets students to raise their eyebrows is Buffon's Needle. The probability a drop of a needle of length $1cm$ onto $1cm$ lined paper will cross a line is $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$. This gives a useful way to estimate $\pi$, too, if you've forgotten it and are trapped on a desert island with only twigs and pack of lined paper (run the experiment a few million times to estimate the probability, take the reciprocal and multiply by $2$).

Another one, which is pretty darn nonintuitive is how being given seemingly useless information can change the probability of an event. Example: If I flip two fair coins and I tell you that at least one of the two coins came up Heads, and ask you what the probability is that both of them are Heads, you may not jump to the correct answer right away (or maybe you will): $\dfrac{1}{3} \approx 0.333$. But here is the fun part. If I instead tell you that at least one of the coins is Heads and was manufactured on a Saturday, will you arrive at the correct answer of $\dfrac{13}{27} \approx 0.481$?

For information on this problem read:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox#Information_about_the_child

Edit: Thought I'd provide some more information on the coin/Saturday thing, because of the comments. If we denote dates with Saturday=1, Sunday=2, etc. Then given the information that *at least one is a Heads and was manufactured on a Saturday* ("Heads 1"). then give dates to all possibilities of both coins, our reduced sample space is:

$$(Heads 1, Heads 1) \\
(Heads 1, Heads 2) \\
(Heads 1, Heads 3) \\
(Heads 1, Heads 4) \\
(Heads 1, Heads 5) \\
(Heads 1, Heads 6) \\
(Heads 1, Heads 7) \\
(Heads 1, Tails 1) \\
(Heads 1, Tails 2) \\
(Heads 1, Tails 3) \\
(Heads 1, Tails 4) \\
(Heads 1, Tails 5) \\
(Heads 1, Tails 6) \\
(Heads 1, Tails 7) \\
(Heads 2, Heads 1) \\
(Heads 3, Heads 1) \\
(Heads 4, Heads 1) \\
(Heads 5, Heads 1) \\
(Heads 6, Heads 1) \\
(Heads 7, Heads 1) \\
(Tails 1, Heads 1) \\
(Tails 2, Heads 1) \\
(Tails 3, Heads 1) \\
(Tails 4, Heads 1) \\
(Tails 5, Heads 1) \\
(Tails 6, Heads 1) \\
(Tails 7, Heads 1)$$

(see https://js.do/caffeinatedlogic/676775)

There are 27 in total, only 13 of which are both Heads. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: Ummmmmm, what??

Comment: Can you explain the coin manufactured on a Saturday please?

Comment: @Ovi See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox#Information_about_the_child

Comment: I find that very hard to believe about the Saturday, after telling the person there is Head, you could then add virtually any fact about the coin and would the probability changes?  Anyway thanks for that, I will be reading it

Comment: Just hold on here!  You give the information that there is a head, and you have to be doing that without bias, you would equally tell us this in any instance that there was at least one head if there was - so 3/4 of the time in other words.  The coin was manufactured on some day of the week with probability 1, so revealing that the day exists is a probability 1 event, no bayesian information.

Comment: If you let people toss the coins and play the game against you, using randomly selected and changing coins, that you don't know about the day of manufacture - then if you bet at your enhanced odds when they tell you a head or a tail with day of week, betting at your enhanced odds will cost you money I reckon.

Comment: @DavidP In reading the article "From all families with two children, one child is selected at random, and the sex of that child is specified to be a boy. This would yield an answer of 1/21/2." So put simply, we pick a child from the 4 possible variants of family, and label the child selected a "boy" (even though its a girl?), then we also observe the gender of the other child in that family. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: What that means is, if you identify a specific child, "the first child is a boy" you get a very different event than "one of the two is a boy" (which actually means at least one of them is a boy)

Comment: Ah i see basically specifying that the first child chosen is "a boy" which implies that we would get "at least one boy in the family" :)

Answer (score -1):

An interesting introductory probability problem is one of basic geometry.  Say you have a circle with an inscribed equilateral triangle.  The question is, if you were to randomly draw a chord on this circle, what is the probability that it will be greater than the side length of the triangle?

You will come to 2 (or possibly more) conclusions.  Thus, this problem emphasizes the importance of being *precise* when stating a question in probability.  Saying "randomly selecting a chord on the circle" is the ambiguous statement that allows one to arrive at several conclusions about the probability.

Comment: This is called Bertrand's paradox, for those who are interested.

Answer (score -1):

there's the rare illness test  - despite no symptoms, a man takes a test for an illness that occurs in one in a billion people.  The test always detects the illness if it is present, and it delivers negative correctly in 99.99% of the cases where there is no illness.

After receiving a positive test for the illness the man is devastated, but soon he realises that he is almost certainly not ill.

Why is that if it is 99.99% accurate?

Answer -

1 in a billion people receive a true positive

one in ten thousand people receive a false positive

~99.99% of people receive a true negative

no false negatives, it always detects the illness

The man is in the first two options, it is 100,000 times more likely that it was a false positive.  False positives are rare, but the disease is much rarer.