# Equivalent of a divergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've read in an article of this site that if you consider the sequence defined for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by
$$
u_0=0 \text{ and }u_{n+1}=\left(u_n\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}
$$
Then the sequence $\displaystyle \left(u_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $1/2$, no problem so far. However, it also explains that the sequence for $\alpha>0$ given by
$$
v_0=0 \text{ and }v_{n+1}=\left(v_n\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}+\alpha
$$
is a divergent sequence but if we let $N$ be the number of iteration needed so that $v_N>2$,it was written that
$$
N\left(\alpha\right)\underset{(0^{+})}{\sim}\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\alpha}}
$$
Is there a way to show this equivalence ?
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689315/interesting-and-unexpected-applications-of-pi/689387#689387) is a link to the article

Comment: *"I've read in an article of this site"* – what about adding a link to that article, so that we know the context?

Comment: The article can be found at https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/dbed/13dae724fed20356b81be91c63fc13b1e1b8.pdf.

Comment: Isn' there already a proof in the article?