# Why does the sum of such series involve $\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, intuition, pi

Why do the sum of such series tend to involve $π$,which belongs to a circle? How does a series as below have anything to do with a circle?

> $$
> \begin{array}{l}
> \frac{1}{1^6}+\frac{1}{3^{6}}+\frac{1}{5^{6}}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^{6}}{960} \\
> \frac{1}{1^{4}}+\frac{1}{3^{4}}+\frac{1}{5^{4}}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^{4}}{96}
> \end{array}
> $$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689315/interesting-and-unexpected-applications-of-pi

Comment: Notice $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^k}=(1-\frac{1}{2^k})\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^k}$ and presence of $\pi$ in $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^k}$ for even $k$ is discussed in question referenced above (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: There's more to $\pi$ than circles!

Comment: @Angina, pi is imo basically related to a circle. That's it's first definition isn't it?

Comment: This isn't completely related to the question, but you would enjoy this playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMVQcT3414TcPMeEYf_VtPM

Comment: That's a little like saying, why is carbon involved in all these chemicals that have nothing to do with coal, Yasir. It may be your opinion that carbon is basically related to coal, but neither carbon nor $\pi$ cares what your opinions are.

Comment: @YasirSadiq Historically Yes. In modern mathematics you define $\pi$ as a certain zero of the cosine, and you define the cosine as a certain solution of a certain differential equation. No more circles involved at this stage.

Comment: To emphasize, some of the videos in the 3Blue1Brown playlist that @Pendronator linked directly address ways to connect a circle to the "Basel problem" that Sil mentioned, which is very closely related to the series presented in the question. So I feel like those videos are a good answer (but not perfect in that they don't focus much on the higher powers in the question).

Comment: On the plus side don't you find it interesting enough that $\pi$ has a humble beginning with circles and presents itself in many diverse areas (including your infinite series)?